# Which one of either "where" or "when" works better with "point"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm a non-native English speaker and I have a troubling question. What is the difference in terms of usage of "when" and "where"?

> "The fact that my action was so embarrassing singled me out to the point [when/where] my friends asked me if  I did so on purpose."
>
> "She was angry to the point [where/when] she punched him and broke his pair of glasses."

There is a similar question online:

> The word POINT can refer to a place or a time, therefore a relative adverb WHERE or WHEN can be used respectively leading a relative clause as a modifier. However, in Longman, it says WHERE is used whether the word refers to a place or a time, whereas in Oxford, an example clearly shows: We had reached the point when there was no money left. Please help specify. Thanks.

So does this mean we can use the two interchangably?

Comment: Even more idiomatically in your examples: just use _that_. “To the point that…” sounds more natural than either here, at least to me.

Comment: To me, "to the point that" sounds familiar, but grammatically poor. Heh heh.

Comment: Depends on the metaphor. Is it a real, physical Point, that you can point at with your finger? If so, _where_. If, on the other hand, it's merely one metaphoric point on the trail of a movement or a process or a story or something that changes in time, then you can use _when_ (though _where_ is also OK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oxford example is not the same as your example. Their usage of "point" is directly linked to the situation, marking a point in time. Therefore, "when" is appropriate.

In your example, my assumption is that you don't mean "until." Rather, you are talking about the *extent* of being singled out. When talking about extent, use "where."